# separating database tasks from spring petclinic app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I want to turn off the spring petclinic's automatic recreation and repopulation of its underlying MySQL database every time the app restarts.  Can anyone show me how to do this?

The web.xml for the app [can be found at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml).  And the other xml config files [can be found at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring).

I prefer to run database scripts separately from the application, using the MySQL command line client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file datasource-config.xml locate the following configuration

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
        <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Just comment out this code, and you should be good to go.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to look into this.  I found the same thing, and then also commented out the lines that define `initLocation` and `dataLocation` in `data-access.properties`.  I am gonna wait a bit to see if anyone else adds any additional steps.  I want to be completely sure that the `recreate/repopulate database on startup` scripts are completely disabled.